# Ionic cloud installation failed - UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@^2.0.0

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-cloud

Trying to setup Ionic cloud but when I execute the following command I got an error.

**Command :**

`npm install @ionic/cloud-angular --save`

**Error :**

> devdactic-push@1.1.1 /Users/use-name/perso/angular/devdactic-push
>       ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@^2.0.0
>       └── @ionic/cloud-angular@0.5.2
>
> ```
> npm WARN @ionic/cloud-angular@0.5.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0 but none was installed.
> npm WARN devdactic-push@1.1.1 No repository field.
> npm WARN devdactic-push@1.1.1 No license field.
> ```

Comment: The same issue with me also